# What is the name of term/rule/guideline for "one is only rewarded once one's efforts are spent"?

Tags: terminology, adverbs

So I'm doing an essay on spoiled child's behaviours and stuck at presenting this point. What I want to write is "... The child will fail to understand .. rule/notion when he proceeds in life.".

Comment: It sounds grammatical if you make *rule/notion* plural.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of "You reap what you sow"; here it would be in the positive sense, of course: you reap the outcome of your efforts.